# Is there any way to trigger a different pipeline inside of a pipeline in Azure Dev Ops

Tags: azure-devops

If I create a variable like IsTrigger and the default value of this variable is false and this value can be set at queque time.

I wonder what happens if I give this variable true as value when I run a pipeline.

Can I trigger a different pipeline based on the value of this variable?

for example:

```
    eq(variables['IsTrigger', true]
```

- do trigger different pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) available from VS Marketplace.

Or using [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) methods Run pipeline. For example via [Invoke REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/invoke-rest-api-v1?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml) task or with bash (script) task:

```
- bash: |
    curl \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer ${SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN}" \
      -X POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=7.0

  displayName: Trigger another pipeline
  condition: eq(variables['IsTrigger', true])
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(system.accesstoken)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do by adding a trigger to the pipeline that you want to be triggered like

```
resources:
  'pipelines:
  - pipeline: MyCIAlias  
    source: MainPipeline
    trigger:    
      stages:        
      - MyStage
```

This will be triggered when the stage "MyStage" in your pipeline "MainPipeline" has completed.

In the MainPipeline on the MyStage you can set a condition that will skip the stage unless your "IsTrigger" variable is set to true, like

````
- stage: MyStage 
  dependsOn: 
  - Build
  displayName: Checklist Pre Production Release
  condition: | 
    eq(variables.IsTrigger, 'true')
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `az` commandline tool and the built-in AccessToken, when you need to trigger a Pipeline inside Azure DevOps on the same Organization.

```yaml
- job:
  displayName: "Run Pipeline"
  steps:
  - bash: |
      az pipelines run --project 'PROJECT' --id 123456 --branch 'main' 
    displayName: 'Trigger Pipeline 123456'
    env:
      AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
```

`az pipelines run` can also set parameters for a pipeline you want to trigger:
`az pipelines run --project 'PROJECT' --id 123456 --branch 'main' --parameters 'param1=VALUE'`
(The ones when you click "Run Pipeline" and can set/select in the UI in the Browser)
Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest#az-pipelines-run

To find the ID of a pipeline:
`az pipelines list -p "ProjectName" | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -Property Id, Name, queueStatus | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "PipelineName" }`